# How can I navigate and describe what this function is trying to achieve from the given assembly code?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, x86-64

From my textbook, I am given the following function in x86-64 assembly:

```
foo:                             # line 1
       movl $0, %eax             # line 2
       movl $0, %r8d             # line 3
       jmp .L2                   # line 4
.L3:                             # line 5
       addl $1, %eax             # line 6
.L2:                             # line 7
       cmpl %esi, %eax           # line 8
       jge .L5                   # line 9
       movslq %eax, %rcx         # line 10
       cmpl %edx, (%rdi,%rcx,4)  # line 11
       jne .L3                   # line 12
       addl $1, %r8d             # line 13 
       jmp .L3                   # line 14
.L5:                             # line 15
       movl %r8d, %eax           # line 16
       ret                       # line 17
```

So far, I think I've been able to figure out the function's C signature with the appropriate C types. Since the size specifiers are all `l`, I assumed it is returning an `int` and all of the arguments for the function are also `int`. Here is what I have:

```
int foo(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
```

From further inspection, this function also contains a for loop. Using variable names that correspond to the register names used (e.g. using `eax` for `%eax`), here is what I think the loop structure is:

```
for (eax = 0; eax < esi; eax++)
```

However, I am having a lot of trouble describing what this function is actually trying to accomplish. The jump instructions and the `movslq %eax, %rcx` are what are making me confused. Can anyone help me navigate the assembly of this function and help me understand what it is trying to achieve? I'm relatively new to assembly and I'm not fully used to reading it. Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated in order to increase my understanding of assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `movslq` you see is actually the [`MOVSX`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movsx:movsxd) instruction, which in AT&T syntax is called MOVSLQ (yeah, silly, I know). You have the suffixes `l` (long = 4 bytes) and `q` (quadruple = 8 bytes) to indicate the size of the two operands. This is a simple move with sign extension from a smaller to a bigger register (in your case EAX to RCX).

The jumps are a little bit convoluted, but you can translate the assembly into pseudo-C code like this:

```
foo:                             # 
       movl $0, %eax             # eax = 0
       movl $0, %r8d             # r8d = 0
       jmp .L2                   # goto L2
.L3:                             # 
       addl $1, %eax             # eax++
.L2:                             # 
       cmpl %esi, %eax           # if (eax >= esi)
       jge .L5                   #     goto L5
       movslq %eax, %rcx         # rcx = eax
       cmpl %edx, (%rdi,%rcx,4)  # if (rdi[rcx] != edx)
       jne .L3                   #     goto L3
       addl $1, %r8d             # r8d++
       jmp .L3                   # goto L3
.L5:                             # 
       movl %r8d, %eax           # 
       ret                       # return r8d
```

The key takeaways here are:

1. x86-64 System V calling convention uses RDI, RSI, RDX, [...] as parameters, RAX as return value.
2. We can see that RDI is used *as is*, while the other two parameters are treated as 4 byte parameters: we only see ESI and EDX appear.
3. The actual value to be returned sits in R8D, and is also 4 bytes.
4. The loop variable is EAX, and the initial `cmpl %esi, %eax; jge .L5` at the start is the control condition of the loop, which means that ESI holds the total length of the array. Furthermore, the `JGE` instruction is *signed* ([see this quick reference](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/x86-jumps.html)), which means that EAX and ESI are treated as signed 4-byte integers (i.e. C `int`).
5. The compare `cmpl %edx, (%rdi,%rcx,4)` makes us understand that RDI is used as the base address of an array of 4-byte elements (e.g. `int`), as this operation dereferences `rdi + rcx * 4` to get a "long" (4 bytes in AT&T jargon, `l` suffix).
6. That compare is checking whether EDX (second argument) is equal to the element at position RCX in the array referenced by RDI. We can see that RCX comes right from EAX, so this is checking the element at the current index.
7. If that compare fails (`jne`), we do not increment R8D. Otherwise if it succeeds, we increment R8D. This is inverted logic, but we can simply negate it to understand that R8D is increased only if the element at the current index is equal to EDX (third argument).

With all of this in mind, we can continue simplifying the code:

```c
int func(int *rdi, int esi, int edx) {
    int eax = 0;
    int r8d = 0;

    for ( ; ; eax++) {
        if (eax >= esi)
            return r8d;

        int rcx = eax;

        if (rdi[rcx] != edx)
            continue;

        r8d++;
    }

    return r8d;
}
```

At this point it should be quite clear what the function does: it scans an array of integers counting the number of elements matching a given value.

We can rewrite it more concisely as:

```c
int func(int *rdi, int esi, int edx) {
    int r8d = 0;
    int eax;

    for (eax = 0; eax < esi; eax++) {
        if (rdi[eax] == edx)
            r8d++;
    }

    return r8d;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your insightful answer. It gave me a lot of help when I did the other problems that were similar to the one I posted. I guess I just wasn't thinking in terms of the x86-64 procedure calling conventions.